# Simultanous VPN on router

Tags: vpn, router

I have questions regarding the following setup:

1. Router is configured to tunnel every connection through a VPN server in country A
2. Additionally, using the software of the same VPN provider on the operating system of an end device, a VPN tunnel is established to a server in country B

So I guess its: Bob -> VPN through Router in country A -> VPN through Client in country B -> Alice

Is this correct? Is this setup the same like a MultiHop configuration?

What exactly happens if VPN in country B is corrupted? For example, traffic from and to VPN server in country B is monitored?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless the VPN provider guarantees it, and possibly not even then, you shouldn't assume that the data just moves from Bob's VPN to Alice's VPN without passing over the wire unencrypted within the VPN provider's facility.  It may even pass over the open internet if the VPN provider has multiple, distributed endpoints.

If Alice and Bob want a guaranteed, encrypted connection they should use a VPN directly between them leaving the provider out of it.  The downside of this is if they set things up directly there won't be a nice prepackaged installer from the VPN provider so the scope for making mistakes is increased.

If the networks in country B are being monitored the people monitoring will be able to see that Alice is using a VPN, roughly how much data she is sending an receiving.  They may be able to infer more through traffic analysis.  They won't be able to see what is being sent and received though.  If it is the government doing the monitoring Alice may get a knock on her door.